# Gloomhaven - movement dance to gain momentum

Tags: gloomhaven

The Brute in our party has an attack that is based on movement. Using 4 movement, does using 4 Move to back out of their hex and back into it 2x count as moving 4 spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they moved 4 spaces then it counts as four.  Where they end is irrelevent.

From the rules on moving :-

> A “Move X” ability allows a character to move up to X number of hexes on the map. Figures
>   (characters and monsters) can move through allies, but cannot move through enemies or
>   obstacles. Traps and other terrain effects of hexes must be resolved when a figure enters them
>   with normal movement. A figure cannot end its movement in the same hex as another figure.
>   Figures can never move through walls.

Note what it doesn't say.  There is nothing to prohibit finishing in the same space.  There is nothing to prohibit moving back and forth between two spaces.  For some attacks and items where number of spaces moved is taken into account then this is a valid tactic.

There is also [This question](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/25247752#25247752) asked on BGG. The designer gave a thumb up to answer confirming a player can finish a move where they started.